# Navigate from PreferenceScreen to another Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-preferences, android-architecture-navigation

Using the Navigation components of Android Jetpack i have a MainActivity which holds 4 different fragments. One of those fragments is the SettingsFragment which has my preferences from an xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="General settings">
        <PreferenceScreen
            android:summary="Choose an account from your list"
            android:title="Accounts">
            <intent android:action="@string/preferences_account_intent_action" />
        </PreferenceScreen>
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="User settings">
        <SwitchPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:key="user_show_notif_content"
            android:summaryOn="Show message content on new notification"
            android:summaryOff="Hide message content on new notification"
            android:title="Message content" />

        <PreferenceScreen
            android:key="gallery"
            android:summary="List of all the files of the application"
            android:title="Gallery">
        </PreferenceScreen>
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

And the SettingsFragment extends the PreferenceFragmentCompat from Android. From all the other fragments i can navigate to each other through the findNavigation utility from the MainActivity.
I want to navigate from SettingsFragment to GalleryFragment when i press the "Gallery" option from the settings.
I have added the GalleryFragment to the MainActivity navigation graph and i have connected the SettingsFragment to GalleryFragment, which creates the action for the Navigator. But how can i catch the gallery click event?
Is there a specific way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your settings fragment, add a preference change listener. Then in the listener, add your navigation code.
Something like this.

```
        val preferenceGallery = preferenceManager.findPreference<Preference>("preferenceIDGallery")!!
        preferenceGallery.let {
            it.setOnPreferenceChangeListener { preference, newValue ->
                    val f = requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
                    val navController: NavController = f.navController //for fragment switch
                    navController.navigate(R.id.fragmentGallery)
                true
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer from @Viatcheslav Ehrmann the solution is the following

```
<PreferenceScreen
            android:key="pref_gallery"
            android:summary="File list of application"
            android:title="Gallery" />
```

and inside the onCreate of the SettingsFragment i do

```
preferenceManager.findPreference<Preference>("pref_gallery")?.let {
            it.setOnPreferenceClickListener {
                findNavController().navigate(SettingsFragmentDirections.actionSettingsFragmentToGalleryFragment())
                true
            }
        }
```